# How to fix "Cannot acquire connection" error while running supertests while working with postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku-postgres

I just started working with postgres and databases and I am getting an error while I am running some tests. The error says "Error: Unable to acquire a connection".

```
 Articles Endpoints
 1) "before all" hook: clean the table in "Articles Endpoints"


 0 passing (36ms)
 1 failing

 1) Articles Endpoints
   "before all" hook: clean the table in "Articles Endpoints":
    Error: Unable to acquire a connection
  at Client_PG.acquireConnection 
  (node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:330:39)
  at Runner.ensureConnection 
  (node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:226:24)
  at Runner.run (node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:33:41)
  at Builder.Target.then 
  (node_modules/knex/lib/interface.js:23:43)



  npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I have researched and the only answers I can find say there is something wrong with knex connection but I cannot find what is wrong with it. Here is my file below that contains the connection.

```
    require("dotenv").config();
    const { expect } = require("chai");
    const knex = require("knex");
    const app = require("../src/app");

    describe.only("Articles Endpoints", function() {
      let db;

      before("make knex instance", () => {
       db = knex({
       client: "pg",
        connection: process.env.TEST_DB_URL
        });
    app.set("db", db);
     });

   after("disconnect from db", () => db.destroy());

   before("clean the table", () => 
       db("blogful_articles").truncate());

    afterEach("cleanup", () => db("blogful_articles").truncate());
```

Comment: Please let me know if anyone wants to see more code or other files if that helps.

Comment: What does the PostgreSQL log file say?

Comment: I realized my TEST_DB_URL was Test_DB_URL in my .env file. I got it working now. Thanks!